# How to display errors with Axios in React

Tags: node.js, api, express, axios

Good day,

i am running to a slight problem with Axios, i want to check if the status code is ok, if not then i send the error to the client. How can i do that ?

This is my attempt to do it, but i had no success:

Route code:

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        //check if fields are empty
        const { name, email, password, rePassword } = req.body;
        if (!name || !email || !password || !rePassword) {
            return res.status(406).send("fields are empty");
        }

        //passsword length should be at leats 6 characters
        if (password.length < 6) {
            return res
                .status(406)
                .send("Password should at least be 6 characters long");
        }
        //checking if passwords match
        if (password !== rePassword) {
            return res.status(406).send("Passwords dont match");
        }
        //check if user exists
        const emailExist = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
        if (emailExist) {
            return res.status(406).send("User already exists");
        } else {
            //create salt
            const salt = await genSalt(10);
            //hashing the password
            const hashedPassword = await hash(req.body.password, salt);
            const user = new User({
                name: req.body.name,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: hashedPassword,
                isAdmin: req.body.isAdmin,
            });
            const newUser = await user.save();
            res.status(200).send(newUser);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Page code:

```
const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios
            .post("http://localhost:5000/users/register", {
                name,
                email,
                password,
                rePassword,
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
            })

            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The response will give you the following options

```
console.log(response.data);
console.log(response.status);
console.log(response.statusText);
console.log(response.headers);
console.log(response.config);
```

This will allow you to check for valid stausText/codes, or display errors accordingly.

Comment: It just shows this:
xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:5000/users/register 406 (Not Acceptable)
Error: Request failed with status code 406
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)